# Is there a better way to do this MYSQL statement?

Tags: mysql

This mysql statement gets posts that have not been flagged by the user.

As it is now, I am getting the flagged post ids, and then not getting posts in that set of ids.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.id NOT IN 
(SELECT p2.id FROM posts p2 LEFT JOIN flagged_posts 
ON flagged_posts.user_id = ? WHERE flagged_posts.post_id = p2.id)
```

I feel there is probably a better (faster) way to do this, for example with just one select and one join, but I am not sure

Comment: I can optimize my answer if you show the tables structure

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using clause `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 
        FROM flagged_posts 
        WHERE flagged_posts.post_id=posts.post_id AND flagged_posts.user_id=?)
```

Alternatively you can do this using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged_posts ON posts.post_id = flagged_posts.post_id 
AND flagged_posts.user_id=?
WHERE flagged_posts.post_id IS NULL
```